# In a list of elements spanning two or more pages, how can I indicate a continuation of the same list?

Tags: word-request, writing

A list I am writing spans over two pages and I want to rewrite the title of the list on the second page to indicate that it is the second part of the list. In French we usually write *"suite"* to indicate that it's the same list. For example:

> **Programming languages**
>
> - C
> - C++
> - Java
> - Python
>
> *--------------- Next page --------------*
>
> **Programming languages** (suite)
>
> - Bash
> - Pascal
> - Perl
> - R
> - Mathematica
> - …

Is "(suite)" used in this context in English, or is there a better option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In English, the common indication is "*(cont.)*", an abbreviation of "continued". Your list would look like this:

> *--------------- Next page --------------*
>
> **Programming languages** (cont.)
>
> - …

However, in general I would recommend not breaking a list over two pages if it's at all avoidable. Readers will appreciate having the content all on one page (this is true of dead trees as well as the Internet) and it reduces mistakes stemming from reader fatigue.

And, of course, if the list is so long as to *require* two pages, it's probably too long in the first place.

**EDIT (I don't normally add this much to an answer, but the O.P. asked for some examples):**

In a book called *A Guide for Using Stone Soup in the Classroom*
by Susan Onion<sup>1</sup>, she uses (*cont*.) to denote an outline that is continuing onto subsequent pages.

[image]

---

#### Also,

a medical textbook entitled Pneumonia Essentials 2010 (Burke Cunha, editor) uses a variant, (cont'd):

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> If you know the *Stone Soup* story, you'll find the author's name rather amusing.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a source for this, since searches for *(cont.)* merely turn up its actual inline use. This is a harder subject to search on than it appears at first glance! References would be appreciated if someone happens to have them at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jonathan I already check your answer even if it is true that a reference would nicely complete your answer.

Comment: +1 for both fair-use of graphics as well as giving credit with corresponding references. Excellent answer.